# The functions getRows and getColumns aren't working right

Tags: javascript, html

`getRows()` and `getColumns()` are supposed to put all the rows and columns into an array with 3 arrays inside. One for each row/column of sub grids (the boxes with nine smaller boxes inside), in that array one for the each row/column of boxes and in that array is all the boxes. But it doesn't seem to work how it supposed to be in the case of `getColumns()` it should return an array with the first element in that array having in order

```
a1,a4,a7,d1,d4,d7,g1,g4,g7,a2,a5,a8,d2,d5,d8...
```

but it doesn't work.

```js
//sorts the different boxes into arrays. To get the the first box in the first subgrid type allBoxes[0][0]
function getBoxes() {
    const xBoxIds =['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i'];
    let allBoxes = []
    for (let i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        let xID = xBoxIds[i];
        let xBoxArray = [];
        for (let i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
            let xIDn = xID + i.toString();
            let xnBoxElement = document.getElementById(xIDn);
            xBoxArray.push(xnBoxElement);
        }
        allBoxes.push(xBoxArray);
    }
    return allBoxes
}
//makes an array with all the columns to get the rightmost column write allColumns[0][0]
function getColumns() {
    let leftBoxColumnsIds = ['a','d','g'];
    let midBoxColumnIds = ['b','e','h'];
    let rightBoxColumnIds = ['c','f','i'];
    let leftBoxColumnIds = ['1','4','7'];
    let midBoxColumnIds = ['2','5','8'];
    let rightBoxColumnIds = ['3','6','9'];
    let boxColumnIds = [leftBoxColumnIds, midBoxColumnIds, rightBoxColumnIds];
    let boxColumnLocations = [leftBoxColumnsIds, midBoxColumnIds, rightBoxColumnIds];
    let allColumns = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        let boxLocation = boxColumnLocations[i];
        let xBoxColumn = [];
        
        for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            let xBoxColumnColumnId = boxLocation[i];
            
            let xBoxColumnColumn = [];  
            
            for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                
                let xBoxColumnColumnN = boxColumnNIds[i];
               let nBoxColumnColumn = xBoxColumnColumnN[i];
               let xIdn = xBoxColumnColumnId + nBoxColumnColumn;
               let box = document.getElementById(xIdn);
               xBoxColumnColumn.push(box);
            }
            xBoxColumn.push(xBoxColumnColumn);
        }
        allColumns.push(xBoxColumn);
        } 
    return allColumns
}  
//makes an array with all the rows to access the highest row write allRows[0][0]
function getRows() {
    let topBoxRowsIds = ['a','b','c'];
    let midBoxRowIds = ['d','e','f'];
    let bottomBoxRowIds = ['g','h','i'];
    let topBoxRowNIds = ['1','2','3'];
    let midBoxRowNIds = ['4','5','6'];
    let bottomBoxRowNIds = ['7','8','9'];
    let boxRowNIds = [topBoxRowNIds, midBoxRowNIds, bottomBoxRowNIds];
    let boxRowLocations = [topBoxRowsIds,midBoxRowIds,bottomBoxRowIds];
    let allRows = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        let boxLocation = boxRowLocations[i];
        let xBoxRow = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            let xBoxRowRowN = boxRowNIds[i];
            let xBoxRowRowId = boxLocation[i];
            let xBoxRowRow = [];
            for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
               let nBoxRowRow = xBoxRowRowN[i];
               let xIdn = xBoxRowRowId + nBoxRowRow;
               let box = document.getElementById(xIdn);
               xBoxRowRow.push(box);
            }
            xBoxRow.push(xBoxRowRow);
        }
        allRows.push(xBoxRow);
    } 
    return allRows
}
function randomGen(){

    var boxes = getBoxes();
    for (let i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
         
        let xSubGrid = boxes[i];
        for (let i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
            
            let box = xSubGrid[i];
            let ranBool = Math.floor(Math.random()*2.5) == 0;
            let ranNum = Math.floor(Math.random()*9) + 1;
            if (ranBool) {
                box.innerHTML  = ranNum.toString();
            } else{
                box.innerHTML = ''
            }
        }
    }
}

function createGame() {
 randomGen()
}
```

```css
.container{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    height: 600px;
    width: 600px;


}
.container > div {
    background-color: black;
    padding: 3px;
    
}
.container > div:nth-child(odd){
    background-color:rgb(0, 0, 0);
}
.subGrid{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    

}
.subGrid > div {
    background-color: gray;
    padding: 1em;
    margin: 1px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div id="a" class = 'subGrid'>
            <div id="a1" class = 'box'></div>
            <div id="a2" class = 'box'></div>
            <div id="a3" class = 'box'></div>
            <div id="a4" class = 'box'></div>
            <div id="a5" class = 'box'></div>
            <div id="a6" class = 'box'></div>
            <div id="a7" class = 'box'></div>
            <div id="a8" class = 'box'></div>
            <div id="a9" class = 'box'></div>
        </div>
         <div id="b" class = 'subGrid'>
            <div id="b1" class = 'box'></div>
            <div id="b2" class = 'box'></div>
            <div id="b3" class = 'box'></div>
            <div id="b4" class = 'box'></div>
            <div id="b5" class = 'box'></div>
            <div id="b6" class = 'box'></div>
            <div id="b7" class = 'box'></div>
            <div id="b8" class = 'box'></div>
            <div id="b9" class = 'box'></div>
        </div>
         <div id="c" class = 'subGrid'>
            <div id="c1" class = 'box'></div>
            <div id="c2" class = 'box'></div>
            <div id="c3" class = 'box'></div>
            <div id="c4" class = 'box'></div>
            <div id="c5" class = 'box'></div>
            <div id="c6" class = 'box'></div>
            <div id="c7" class = 'box'></div>
            <div id="c8" class = 'box'></div>
            <div id="c9" class = 'box'></div>
        </div>
        <div id="d" class = 'subGrid'>
            <div id="d1" class = 'box'></div>
            <div id="d2" class = 'box'></div>
            <div id="d3" class = 'box'></div>
            <div id="d4" class = 'box'></div>
            <div id="d5" class = 'box'></div>
            <div id="d6" class = 'box'></div>
            <div id="d7" class = 'box'></div>
            <div id="d8" class = 'box'></div>
            <div id="d9" class = 'box'></div>
        </div>
        <div id="e" class = 'subGrid'>
            <div id="e1" class = 'box'></div>
            <div id="e2" class = 'box'></div>
            <div id="e3" class = 'box'></div>
            <div id="e4" class = 'box'></div>
            <div id="e5" class = 'box'></div>
            <div id="e6" class = 'box'></div>
            <div id="e7" class = 'box'></div>
            <div id="e8" class = 'box'></div>
            <div id="e9" class = 'box'></div>
        </div>
        <div id="f" class = 'subGrid'>
            <div id="f1" class = 'box'></div>
            <div id="f2" class = 'box'></div>
            <div id="f3" class = 'box'></div>
            <div id="f4" class = 'box'></div>
            <div id="f5" class = 'box'></div>
            <div id="f6" class = 'box'></div>
            <div id="f7" class = 'box'></div>
            <div id="f8" class = 'box'></div>
            <div id="f9" class = 'box'></div>
        </div> 
        <div id="g" class = 'subGrid'>
            <div id="g1" class = 'box'></div>
            <div id="g2" class = 'box'></div>
            <div id="g3" class = 'box'></div>
            <div id="g4" class = 'box'></div>
            <div id="g5" class = 'box'></div>
            <div id="g6" class = 'box'></div>
            <div id="g7" class = 'box'></div>
            <div id="g8" class = 'box'></div>
            <div id="g9" class = 'box'></div>
        </div>
        <div id="h" class = 'subGrid'>
            <div id="h1" class = 'box'></div>
            <div id="h2" class = 'box'></div>
            <div id="h3" class = 'box'></div>
            <div id="h4" class = 'box'></div>
            <div id="h5" class = 'box'></div>
            <div id="h6" class = 'box'></div>
            <div id="h7" class = 'box'></div>
            <div id="h8" class = 'box'></div>
            <div id="h9" class = 'box'></div>
        </div>
        <div id="i" class = 'subGrid'>
            <div id="i1" class = 'box'></div>
            <div id="i2" class = 'box'></div>
            <div id="i3" class = 'box'></div>
            <div id="i4" class = 'box'></div>
            <div id="i5" class = 'box'></div>
            <div id="i6" class = 'box'></div>
            <div id="i7" class = 'box'></div>
            <div id="i8" class = 'box'></div>
            <div id="i9" class = 'box'></div>
        </div>       
    </div>
    <button onclick="createGame()">Create Game</button>
    <button onclick="solveGame()">Solve Game</button>
    <script src="creator.js"></script>
    <script src="solver.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: When the above code snippet is run, this is the error that is displayed - "Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'midBoxColumnIds' has already been declared"

Answer (score 0):

Would tell, you are overcomplicated things ;-)

Made cols by rows as they was a bit easier to fix and 3 small test functions.

```js
//sorts the different boxes into arrays. To get the the first box in the first subgrid type allBoxes[0][0]
function getBoxes() {
    const xBoxIds =['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i'];
    let allBoxes = []
    for (let i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        let xID = xBoxIds[i];
        let xBoxArray = [];
        for (let i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
            let xIDn = xID + i.toString();
            let xnBoxElement = document.getElementById(xIDn);
            xBoxArray.push(xnBoxElement);
        }
        allBoxes.push(xBoxArray);
    }
    return allBoxes
}
//makes an array with all the columns to get the rightmost column write allColumns[0][0]
function getColumns() {
    let boxRowNIds = [
        '147'.split(''),
        '258'.split(''),
        '369'.split('')];
    let boxRowLocations = [
        'adg'.split(''),
        'beh'.split(''),
        'cfi'.split('')];
    return getGeneral(boxRowLocations, boxRowNIds);
}
function getRows() {
    let boxRowNIds = [
        ['1','2','3'],
        ['4','5','6'],
        ['7','8','9']
    ];
    let boxRowLocations = [
        ['a','b','c'],
        ['d','e','f'],
        ['g','h','i']
    ];
    return getGeneral(boxRowLocations, boxRowNIds);
}
//makes an array with all the rows to access the highest row write allRows[0][0]
function getGeneral(boxRowLocations, boxRowNIds) {
    let allRows = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        let boxLocation = boxRowLocations[i];
        let xBoxRow = [];
        for (let i0 = 0; i0 < 3; i0++) {
            for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                let xBoxRowRowN = boxRowNIds[i0];
                let xBoxRowRowId = boxLocation[i];
                let xBoxRowRow = [];
                for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                    let nBoxRowRow = xBoxRowRowN[i];
                    let xIdn = xBoxRowRowId + nBoxRowRow;
                    let box = document.getElementById(xIdn);
                    xBoxRowRow.push(box);
                    }
                xBoxRow.push(xBoxRowRow);
            }
        }
        allRows.push(xBoxRow);
    }

    return allRows
}
function randomGen(){

    var boxes = getBoxes();
    for (let i = 0; i < 9; i++) {

        let xSubGrid = boxes[i];
        for (let i = 0; i < 9; i++) {

            let box = xSubGrid[i];
            let ranBool = Math.floor(Math.random()*2.5) == 0;
            let ranNum = Math.floor(Math.random()*9) + 1;
            if (ranBool) {
                box.innerHTML  = ranNum.toString();
            } else{
                box.innerHTML = ''
            }
        }
    }
}

function createGame() {
 randomGen()
}
// Test & report functions
var itemsNo;
function examine(arrays) {
    itemsNo = 0;
    markArrays(arrays);
    alert('Found ' + itemsNo + ' values\n' + JSON.stringify(arrays));
}
function markArrays(arrays) {
    for(var a in arrays) {
        if (arrays[a] instanceof Array) markArrays(arrays[a]);
        else {
            itemsNo++;
            //arrays[a].innerText = arrays[a].id;
            arrays[a] = arrays[a].innerText || [a].id;
        }
    }
}
function markById() {
    var c = document.getElementsByClassName("container");
    var l1 = c[0].children;
    for(var l in l1) {
        l = l1[l];
        var parentId = l.id;
        l2 = l.children;
        for(var l in l2) {
            l2[l].innerText = l2[l].id
        }
    }
}
```

```css
.container{
    display: grid;grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr;height: 600px;width: 600px;
}
.container > div {
    background-color: black;padding: 3px;}
.container > div:nth-child(odd){
    background-color:rgb(0, 0, 0);
}
.subGrid{
    display: grid;grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}
.subGrid > div {
    background-color: gray;padding: 1em;margin: 1px;text-align: center;font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<div class="container"><div id="a" class = 'subGrid'><div id="a1" class = 'box'></div><div id="a2" class = 'box'></div><div id="a3" class = 'box'></div><div id="a4" class = 'box'></div><div id="a5" class = 'box'></div><div id="a6" class = 'box'></div><div id="a7" class = 'box'></div><div id="a8" class = 'box'></div><div id="a9" class = 'box'></div></div><div id="b" class = 'subGrid'><div id="b1" class = 'box'></div><div id="b2" class = 'box'></div><div id="b3" class = 'box'></div><div id="b4" class = 'box'></div><div id="b5" class = 'box'></div><div id="b6" class = 'box'></div><div id="b7" class = 'box'></div><div id="b8" class = 'box'></div><div id="b9" class = 'box'></div></div><div id="c" class = 'subGrid'><div id="c1" class = 'box'></div><div id="c2" class = 'box'></div><div id="c3" class = 'box'></div><div id="c4" class = 'box'></div><div id="c5" class = 'box'></div><div id="c6" class = 'box'></div><div id="c7" class = 'box'></div><div id="c8" class = 'box'></div><div id="c9" class = 'box'></div></div><div id="d" class = 'subGrid'><div id="d1" class = 'box'></div><div id="d2" class = 'box'></div><div id="d3" class = 'box'></div><div id="d4" class = 'box'></div><div id="d5" class = 'box'></div><div id="d6" class = 'box'></div><div id="d7" class = 'box'></div><div id="d8" class = 'box'></div><div id="d9" class = 'box'></div></div><div id="e" class = 'subGrid'><div id="e1" class = 'box'></div><div id="e2" class = 'box'></div><div id="e3" class = 'box'></div><div id="e4" class = 'box'></div><div id="e5" class = 'box'></div><div id="e6" class = 'box'></div><div id="e7" class = 'box'></div><div id="e8" class = 'box'></div><div id="e9" class = 'box'></div></div><div id="f" class = 'subGrid'><div id="f1" class = 'box'></div><div id="f2" class = 'box'></div><div id="f3" class = 'box'></div><div id="f4" class = 'box'></div><div id="f5" class = 'box'></div><div id="f6" class = 'box'></div><div id="f7" class = 'box'></div><div id="f8" class = 'box'></div><div id="f9" class = 'box'></div></div><div id="g" class = 'subGrid'><div id="g1" class = 'box'></div><div id="g2" class = 'box'></div><div id="g3" class = 'box'></div><div id="g4" class = 'box'></div><div id="g5" class = 'box'></div><div id="g6" class = 'box'></div><div id="g7" class = 'box'></div><div id="g8" class = 'box'></div><div id="g9" class = 'box'></div></div><div id="h" class = 'subGrid'><div id="h1" class = 'box'></div><div id="h2" class = 'box'></div><div id="h3" class = 'box'></div><div id="h4" class = 'box'></div><div id="h5" class = 'box'></div><div id="h6" class = 'box'></div><div id="h7" class = 'box'></div><div id="h8" class = 'box'></div><div id="h9" class = 'box'></div></div><div id="i" class = 'subGrid'><div id="i1" class = 'box'></div><div id="i2" class = 'box'></div><div id="i3" class = 'box'></div><div id="i4" class = 'box'></div><div id="i5" class = 'box'></div><div id="i6" class = 'box'></div><div id="i7" class = 'box'></div><div id="i8" class = 'box'></div><div id="i9" class = 'box'></div></div></div>
<button onclick="createGame()">Create Game</button>
<button onclick="solveGame()">Solve Game</button>
<button onclick="examine(getRows())">getRows</button>
<button onclick="examine(getColumns())">getColumns</button>
<button onclick="markById()">Put ID to cells</button>
```

And 3 buttons - 2 fixed functions and 3rd to fill empty cells by their IDs to have test data when printing result arays content by examine function.